# Using Multiple Columns in a SQL Subquery

Tags: sql, sql-server

My setup is I have two tables, Study and Activity_History. Activities run on studies so there is a 1:many relationship.

I want to be able to run a SQL query on an Activity_History table which will get me the activity and the previously run activity. I currently have this:

```
SELECT 
        *
FROM Activity_History AS A1
LEFT JOIN Activity_History AS A2
ON A2.Parent_Study_ID =
(
    SELECT TOP 1 Parent_Study_ID
    FROM Activity_History AS A3
    WHERE A3.Parent_Study_ID = A1.Parent_Study_ID 
          AND A3.Activity_Date < A1.Activity_Date
    ORDER BY Activity_Date DESC
)
```

This is not working. What's happening is its pulling the Activity_Date party of the query has no effect and it just returns the first matching Activity_Date in descending date order for every row. I think this is happening because in my subquery I am using Activity_Date in the where, but this is not in the subquery select.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: can you please add the table schema , columns name

Comment: What does "*This is not working*" mean?

Comment: You shouldn't need to include all the columns in your `WHERE` in your `SELECT`... what's the error that you're getting?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm assuming you're using SQL Server?  If so, then this should work using ROW_NUMBER():

```
WITH CTE AS (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Parent_Study_Id ORDER BY Activity_Date ) RN
    FROM Activity_History
    )
SELECT * 
FROM CTE T1
    LEFT JOIN CTE T2 ON T1.RN = T2.RN+1 AND T1.Parent_Study_Id  = T2.Parent_Study_Id
```

And here is the [SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/fed86/2).

Comment: The correct expression is `row_number() over (partition by parent_study_id order by activity_date)`.

Comment: @GordonLinoff -- thanks, didn't see that in original query -- working on Fiddle and went too fast!  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In SQLServer2005+ instead LEFT JOIN you need to use [OUTER APPLY](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175156%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

```
SELECT *
FROM Activity_History AS A1 OUTER APPLY ( 
                                         SELECT TOP 1 Parent_Study_ID
                                         FROM Activity_History AS A2
                                         WHERE A2.Parent_Study_ID = A1.Parent_Study_ID 
                                           AND A2.Activity_Date < A1.Activity_Date
                                         ORDER BY A2.Activity_Date DESC
                                         ) o
```